# Why is the fuel:air ratio of a turbojet engine not around ~1:15 (the stoichiometric ratio)?

Tags: jet-engine, engine, turbojet, combustion, mixture

Also, what is the maximum fuel:air ratio possible in a combustion chamber of a jet engine?

Comment: Would you please provide some sources for your information?

Comment: I think this question should be rolled back, the latest edit of ditching the f/a ratio of 1/4-1/3 totally changes the question. As it stands now, this is a very good question, but it is **not** what Call Me Dosya asked originally.

Comment: If one would take a look at the %fuel/air combustible range for Jet A1 kerosene (Engineering Toolbox), it is around 0.7 to 5%.  So 1/4 to 1/3 would be way too rich.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Edit: to honor my original answer, I shall keep it as it is. The question was edited so much I think it would have constituted a whole new question. In it's original form, the Q presented jet engine f/a ratio as 1/4 - 1/3 and compared it to the stoich ratio of 1/15.*

Your numbers seem way off, except for the stoichiometric fuel/air ratio (for kerosene).

Please see the following NASA article: [Beginner's Guide to Propulsion and EngineSim
Fuel and Air Relationships
Activity](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/BGP/PAT/Fuel_and_Air2_act.htm)

A quote from there:

> For jet engine combustion, the important parameter is the fuel/air ratio (f/a) which is the ratio of the mass of fuel to the mass of air being burned in the engine.

The stoichiometric ratio of 1/15 can also be written as approximately 0.067

The article further elaborates on the subject:

> For example, at sea level an airliner taking off at 375 mph with the throttle at 100% has an f/a of .017

This 0.017 translates into about 1/59

No matter how you look at the ratio, mass or volume, in no case will a jet engine run at f/a of 1/4~1/3. The mixture will simply be too rich to ignite and burn.

Here is a link to a Wikipedia graph about the range of typical jet engine air:fuel ratios:

[Combustion stability limits of aircraft gas turbine.svg](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Combustion_stability_limits_of_aircraft_gas_turbine.svg#mw-jump-to-license)

Please note the graph displays the ratio in reverse order from what was used before in this answer, ranging from ~25/1 to ~180/1.

Answer (score 2):

We have to remember air is only 20% oxygen.  When you write the stoichimetric formula for the chemical reaction (using oxygen) on a *molar* basis, you get the combustion ratio by converting the fuel and oxidizer from moles to mass.

To get the combustion ratio using **air**, you divide the oxygen mass by its fractional proportion in air.

Interestingly, the stoichimetric fuel/**oxygen** ratio (by mass) *is* around 1:3. 3 divided by 0.21 gives us around 15 for kerosene and air.

Turbojets burn fuel in combustion "cans" within the flammable fuel/air percentage limits and use the heat from that combustion to warm *more air* passing through the the core.

Bypass fans can make these ratios even higher.  For example, the Ge 90 has a bypass ratio of **9 to 1**.  Of the 10% of the total air mass flow going through the core, its air to fuel ratio is around **33 to 1**, much higher than stoichiometric.

The **total** air to fuel ratio (by mass) is **330 to 1**!

One can see why fuel combustion "cans" were invented, and why fan jets are becoming more popular.

Comment: When calculating a/f ratio, you can not take into account the bypass air. It is the same as if one would calculate the a/f ratio of a propeller acft and count into it the air the propeller is moving 

Comment: @Jpe61 that is true.  The total air moved is interesting.  Prop thrust may be more related to its lift that "air moved".  More to write about.

Comment: Lift *is* pretty much the air moved.